# Сортировка JTable после добавления очередной строки

Tags: java, swing

Необходимо сортировать JTable (Object[][] data, Object[] headers) после каждого добавления строки (строка формируется из данных, находящихся в БД)

Почитал документацию, попробовал сделать так :

```
private void initDataTable() {
    deviceTable = new JTable();
    deviceTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(null, HEADERS) {
            public boolean isCellEditable(int nRow, int nCol) {
                return false;
            }
    });

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) deviceTable.getModel();

    TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(deviceTable.getModel());
    sorter.setComparator(0, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
            return o1.compareTo(o2);
        }
    });
    sorter.setSortsOnUpdates(true);
    deviceTable.setRowSorter(sorter);

    List<Device> deviceList = QueryHandler.getInfoAsList();
    deviceList.sort(new Device.Comparator());
    for (Device device : deviceList) {
        refreshRow(device, model);
    }

}
```

А метод добавления новых столбцов (через форму)

```
static void refreshRow(Device device, DefaultTableModel model) {
    model.addRow(new Object[] {device.getTitle(), device.getSerialNumber(), device.getInventoryNumber(),
            device.getLastCheckDate(), device.getResponsibleName(), device.getTechnicalStatement(),
            device.getNote()});
    model.fireTableDataChanged();
    deviceTable.repaint();
    deviceTable.revalidate();
}
```

Где model - DefaultTableModel, deviceTable - JTable

Но не сортирует сразу (только после щелчка по заголовку)

Comment: попробуйте сначала установить компаратор, потом добавлять записи

Comment: попробуйте последние две строки местами поменять

Comment: @Виктор нет, все-равно не работает.

Comment: @zRrr Ваш вариант тоже не подходит :(

Comment: Попробуйте на таблице вызывать методы `repaint()` и `revalidate()`

Comment: @Bleser тоже не работает

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение было найдено на английской версии Stack Overflow (source  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024367/sorting-jtable-after-adding-rows)

Оказывается, нужно было просто использовать SortKey

```
List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<RowSorter.SortKey>();
sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(0, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
sorter.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
table.setRowSorter(sorter);
```

Но нужно не забывать, что сортировка проходит лишь визуально ! (Позиции остаются прежними, и поэтому чтобы обращаться к ним, используем методы table.convertRowToIndexModel(int index) и table.convertRowIndexToView(int ind)).

Всем удачи и спасибо